# Are staff members marked as moderators for every site they join?

Tags: support, stack-exchange-team

I looked at Catija's profile and noticed that she was a staff member. I also noticed that *all* of the communities she was part of (even the one's with just 101 default rep), she was marked as a moderator. This brought a question to my mind: Are staff members marked as moderators for every site they join? Or is it just specific staff members?

[image: Catija accounts]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Community Managers get mod diamonds by default on every community. *Not* all employees get mod diamonds and not everywhere - [they're given out as needed.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75189/who-are-the-diamond-moderators-and-what-is-their-role#comment182317_75192). Community managers... well need them a lot of the time.

There's also an employee or two who're proper site mods on specific sites as well, from before they were employed.

The's a [separate "employee" flag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331654/employee-profiles-are-now-marked-with-a-staff-indicator) in the API that wasn't exposed on the website until recently, so at least in theory you can tell when someone is an employee, whether or not they have a diamond