# Is there a maximum height of sidebar ads?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, advertising

Today I saw a big ad with width 300, height 600, a sidebar ad on [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour). This is quite annoying because I frequently visit Cross Validated at work.

[image: hk-12sep2019]

Comment: It should only be 250 pixels high.

Comment: @Sonic where did you see it? From what I know, SE does not limit their ad providers anymore.

Comment: @Sonic if you mean the CSS height imposed in the HTML, it's very easy to bypass by simple JS used by the ad provider..

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog There are different ad sizes allowed now, I've seen them myself.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky isn't this status-bydesign?

Comment: @Luuklag Well, it seems to be tricky: as I understand from the accepted answer bellow 300x600 should be allowed only for some set of partners and it was a test run. On the other hand, technically that was not a bug. So... Let me correct the tag line as you suggested if it makes more sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thank you for reporting this. It's very helpful. We were testing and will be restricting the 300x600 for most campaigns. However, you will potentially see those type banners for some of our premium endemic partners.

Comment: Quick question: will these "premium endemic partners" also be allowed to run animated ads and use Flash?

Comment: (Why isn't there an indication for staff, as for moderators?)

Comment: @PeterMortensen There is, but it's on the [profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/576461/terry-guyton-bradley), as explained [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331654/352819)

Comment: @Secespitus It's actually also in the user card but those only expand once a user has 1k reputation, so it doesn't apply here. :(

Comment: @Catija There should probably be a minor feature-request to make the usercard expendable for staff regardless of reputation.

Comment: @Mast I don’t think we know that on page load, so it’d be expensive to add. I think there’s discussion internally about just giving everyone expanding usercards. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/336683/284336

Comment: @Catija That would probably be the most sensible way to fix it at this point, yes.