# Drop shadows on avatars eligible for expanded usercard has disappeared

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design, user-card

According to the [privilege page for established user rights](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user), there is supposed to be a drop shadow next to avatars that expand upon mouse over into expanded usercards.

However, as of today, that drop shadow has disappeared. Can it please be re-added?

You can test this bug out using my avatar just below; it expands, but no longer shows a shadow as it used to before.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is apparently [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), according to [SO employee Aaron Shekey](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/390765/6083675) on MSO:

> This intentional, but not ideal at the moment. I plan on having a preview card on every user. In my opinion, it's weird UX having it on some users and not all, regardless of a drop shadow or a bio.
>
> I'll update the help article to be more accurate tomorrow. Thanks for pointing it out!

Personally, I'd rather have drop shadows for everyone then. After all, not everywhere you see a username lets you see the card (such as the question list). And not everyone waves the mouse around to see what has a hover.

Also I am not sure how this will work for people that have nothing in their profile to show, because it seems pointless to expand and show no new information.

Comment: "I am not sure how this will work for people that have nothing in their profile to show,  ...", you need [> 28 characters in your "About Me"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user) along 1000 rep. It would be better to have a drop shadow when the feature is active and not present when it's not enabled, since touch screen users need to be particularly skillful to use mouseover on SE.