# Text color on "Moderator" and "Staff" labels is hard to read

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page, user-labels

The "Moderator" and "Staff" labels on employee/moderator profiles have black colored text now:

[image: badges]

Especially the "Moderator" label is pretty hard to read now, so this is probably unintended. The text [has been white originally](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331654/505672):

[image: old labels]

This behaviour shows in both up-to-date Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: For example, on this page: https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/284336/catija

Comment: Ugh, white was much better here. Serious lack of contrast now.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A fix will be deployed soon. Thanks for pointing it out!