# Text color change for "Staff" and "Moderator" indicator

Tags: feature-request, design, profile-page, stack-exchange-team

As per the [post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331654/312043), Employee profiles are marked with a "Staff" and "Moderator" indicator. The below screenshot was taken from the announcement post.

> [image: Old UI]

The below is the current screenshot taken from the user profile. The text color of "Staff" and "Moderator" were changed to black from white. Due to that change, it has less readability.

> [image: New UI]

Can the text color be changed to white again?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Text color on "Moderator" and "Staff" badges is hard to read](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/345009/text-color-on-moderator-and-staff-badges-is-hard-to-read)

Comment: @JanWichelmann I prepared the screenshots and spent time to find the original announcement post.

Comment: Yeah, good point, I should have added that to my original report too.

Comment: Should we flip the duplicate closures? Reopen this one and close yours, @JanWichelmann?

Comment: Sure, I don't mind, IMO this one gives a better comparison for old vs. new. Although it is lacking a freehand circle... ;)

Comment: On second thought, perhaps you should just include the additional screenshots? And we could leave these closed as they are. Doesn't look like we're getting too much attention just yet, which is fine. @JanWichelmann